# pressure wave propagation of shockwaves?

Tags: aerodynamics, shock-waves

I can’t find a simple explanation of how the pressure waves propagate that leads to a shock over an aerofoil online.

How does this happen with upstream flow that is high speed but subsonic?

Comment: You should ask "please" at least seven time to get an answer 

Comment: Isn't this the same as your last question https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/101538/7532